# Comparing 2 directories and their sub-directories: du.exe

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, comparison, file-compare

In a batch program, with Windows XP and Windows 7:

Comparing 2 directories and their sub-directories:
D:\temp        (source)
E:\1\temp      (destination)

On destination drive (E:), this command is working:
du -b -s "E:\1\temp" >e:\du_E1temp_Output.txt
589657708       E:\1\temp

How to get the text output to be (minus 4 characters E:\1  )?
589657708       \temp

On source drive (D:), this command is working:
du -b -s "D:\temp" >e:\du_Dtemp_Output.txt
589657708   D:\temp

How to get the text output to be (minus 2 characters D: )?
589657708       \temp

How to remove characters from the text file?
A different  du.exe  command switch? or
A program to remove characters from a text file?

Why?
Trying to verify that a copy-operation completed successfully.
The above is one (1) test of many tests.

Comparing bytes in 2 directories and their sub-directories
D:\temp        (source)
E:\1\temp      (destination)

Run  du.exe  inside the Source and Destination and then
output to a text file and then
diff the results.

Ideally, in the case below are
2 text files from
2 directories on
2 drives D: and E: and  diff.exe  would report no difference in 2 files:
589657708       \temp
589657708       \temp

Using
"C:\Program Files\Gow\bin\du.exe"
du (GNU coreutils) 5.3.0
2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

How to remove  E:\1  from the text file #1?
How to remove  D:\  from the text file #2?

--

Update:
Here is a batch, initial testing looks good.

If you know of another aggergate Checksum Hash Tool or
how to make a better batch then do suggest.

cls
@echo off
echo Generate MD5 Checksum (Fingerprint Hash) 1.9.0.149 www.fastsum.com
echo Hash for d:\temp\
"C:\Program Files\FastSum\fsum.exe" "d:\temp*.*"   /T:R /R /O | find.exe "Processed"

ren d:\temp\temp.md5 Dtemp.md5

move d:\temp\Dtemp.md5 e:\textLOG\

::

"C:\Program Files\FastSum\fsum.exe" "e:\1\temp*.*" /T:R /R /O | find.exe "Processed"
echo Hash for e:\1\temp\
ren e:\1\temp\temp.md5 Etemp.md5
move e:\1\temp\Etemp.md5 e:\textLOG\
::
echo Diff.exe Hash (Checksum Fingerprint)
"C:\Program Files\Vim\vim80\DIFF.exe" -r -q "e:\textLOG\Dtemp.md5" "e:\textLOG\Etemp.md5"
echo %errorlevel%
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (@echo 0 = ok = Diff.exe errorLevel) else (@echo Problem, *not* errorLevel = 0)
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO !ERROR
echo ___________________________________________________
pause

--

Comment: Are you sure that du is the right program for this purpose? Try generating hashes for every file in both directories and compare them with diff.

Comment: Or `diff -uwr` or something

Comment: Not sure I totally follow you but would comp do what you need? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490883.aspx

Comment: COMP will not do.  About 6000 folders and about 43000 files and about 53GBytes to compare.  For a Windows batch file program (command line), what free Hash Checksum Tool do you recommend?

Comment: fciv.exe,     https://download.microsoft.com/download/c/f/4/cf454ae0-a4bb-4123-8333-a1b6737712f7/Windows-KB841290-x86-ENU.exe ?

Comment: @atype If you go over the contents of every file to create hashes, why not compare the actual contents themselves already?

Comment: Try `ROBOCOPY “SourceFolder” “ComparisonFolder” /e /l /ns /njs /njh /ndl /fp /log:reconcile.txt` as listed [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/diffutils.htm). Or you can use `diff` like @barrycarter said; you can get `diff` for Windows [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/diffutils.htm).

Comment: @tomer-godinger, comparing hashes would be faster, and hash-function and comparing hashes will be faster with large number of files.

Comment: @atype: In order to calculate the hashes of the two files you want to compare, you need to go over their entire contents. If you compare their contents directly then you go over their ccontents and you're done. If you compare their hashes then you go over their contents and then also compare the resulting hashes. Why is that faster? Also, the amount of files is irrelevant if you need to compare all of them anyway.